# PHP to display string 0

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I need help with this code all i need is to display a string "0" to the empty hit data so what i have in mind is day 1 has 3 hits and day 2 has 0 hits, i really have no idea how to display the 0 please help me. thank you

```
days || Hits
 1 - | | |- 3
 2 - | | |- 
 3 - | | |-
 4 - | | |- 
 5 - | | |- 5
```

here's the code:

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = $_POST['selected_date'];
if(!isset($month) or $_POST['selected_date'] == 0)
{
  $month = date("n");
}
 $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
    { 
     echo "<p >$i - ";

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%m') as 'month', DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%d') as 'day',
COUNT(`LookbookLogID`) as 'total'
FROM LookbookLog
where Lookbook_LookbookID = $LookbookID and LookbookLogDate like '%2013-03%'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%m'), DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%d')");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
               $day = $row['day'];

           $total = $row['total'];

             if($day == $i) echo $total."</p>";
        }


    }
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 1):

I would get the zero from the database, since there is a universal SQL function which achieves a good solution:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%m') as 'month',
DATE_FORMAT(`LookbookLogDate`, '%d') as 'day',
COALESCE(COUNT(`LookbookLogID`),0) as 'total'
FROM LookbookLog
{snip}
```

This means if there's no value in the results for COUNT() it will select 0 instead. Then your echo statements will proceed to work fine without checking especially for the NULL case in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the empty() function, the empty() function considers many things as a true value, for a list of these values have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
$total = (empty($row['total'])?0:$row['total']);
```

**Update:**

You should only need to do the below to get the results you are looking for.

```
$total = ($row['total']?$row['total']:0);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do `echo 0` it will display 0 on the screen, however if you do `echo false` it will not display it. Now the problem that you have is not with displaying **0** but its in what value **$total** holds. If your query returns empty set then your `$row['total']` is either `false` or `null` and therefore `echo false` or `echo null` will not display anything.

check to make sure your query returns something and that `$total` holds the desired value using `var_dump` to see the type of it.

You would need something like

```
   $total = ! empty($row['total']) ? $row['total'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Why not just make the field an `int` and set the default value to `0` ?

You don't show any code of how you build your table, but you would do:

```
$total = ((!$row['total'] ? 0 : $row['total']);
```

This code basically says "if `$row['total']` is blank, make it zero. Otherwise, make the `$total` equal to whatever was returned.

Comment: what if total is null or false

Comment: @GGio Good point, updated

Comment: @GGio Aren't false, null and '' all equal in PHP?

Comment: @BrendanLong No, - "" and NULL are completely different things.

Comment: @Evan Yes, they're different things, but they're still equal in PHP (unless you use `===`). See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a variable can be empty (`""`) without being `null`, even when using the `==` operator. I'm going to check your link though - thanks!

Comment: @Evan Yes, they're different values, but they're both considered `false` when used in boolean expressions like `?` or when you compare them using `==`

Comment: @BrendanLong Thank for the explanation. Now I undestand. Post edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `COUNT(...)` returns NULL instead of 0 if there are no results, which presumably PHP treats as an empty string when you output it. You can fix that by either adding an [`COALESCE` expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to your SQL (in my opinion, this is the better solution):

```
SELECT ... COALESCE(COUNT(`LookbookLogID`), 0) ...
```

Or check it in PHP:

```
echo $row['total'] ? $row['total'] : 0;
```

Or the multi-line version:

```
if($row['total'])
    echo $row['total'];
else
    echo 0;
```

Note that you don't need to do any comparisons or call `empty()`, because PHP's type casting [treats null, empty string and 0 as false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).